# row number in sql -keep it same for change in value

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a SQL questions: I want to populate rank for each record as a next up number. However I want to keep the rank same for records for which the adjust values are not same.

Sample data :

```
# | value | date1      | * rank (expected)
--+-------+------------+-------
1 | A     | 05/01/2020 |    1
1 | A     | 05/02/2020 |    2
1 | A     | 05/03/2020 |    3
1 | B     | 05/04/2020 |    3
1 | A     | 05/05/2020 |    3
1 | A     | 05/06/2020 |    4
1 | A     | 05/07/2020 |    5
1 | A     | 05/08/2020 |    6
1 | B     | 05/09/2020 |    6
1 | A     | 05/10/2020 |    6
1 | A     | 05/11/2020 |    7
```

I am looking for best way to populate the 4th column based on the first three.

Comment: Please describe the logic you want, in words. It is not obvious from your data.

Comment: In addition to explaining the logic, please provide a database tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide a good explanation for the logic.  But you seem to want to not count "B"s and the "A" on the next row.

This can be phrased as the following equation:

- The row number minus
- twice the number of Bs up to that row (to get the following row as well)
- plus 1 if the row is B (because we just over subtracted the next row).

This can be implemented as:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (partition by num order by date1) -
        2 * count(*) filter (where value = 'B') over (order by date1) +
        (value = 'B')::int
       )
from t
order by num, date1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=693195dcb183c7c33a6e6a86eb98123d) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to increment the counter only when the value on the current row is the same as in the previous row. You can do this with `lag()` and a cumulative `sum()`:

```
select id, value, date1,
    sum(case when lag_value <> value then 0 else 1 end) as rnk
from (
    select t.*,
        lag(value) over(order by date1) as lag_value
    from mytable t
)
```